# How to get a laravel 5.3 app to autoreload when SASS/JS changes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sass, webpack

Want to auto reload the page whenever I change my SASS or Javascript, but not sure how to do it with WebPack in laravel 5.3. I heard about hot module replacement but it seems really complex is there a way I can integrate it into my gulpfile.

Gulpfile:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for your application as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

EDIT (Tried BrowserSync but its not updating)

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
var BrowserSync = require('laravel-elixir-browsersync-official');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for your application as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js')
       .browserSync({
             port: 8000,
             proxy: 'localhost'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like `browserSync`.

To install `browserSync` run:

```
npm install laravel-elixir-browsersync-official --save
```

Then in your `gulpfile` simply add:

```
.browserSync({
    proxy: 'app.dev',
})
```

(change `app.dev` to your actual app url)

Then when you run `gulp watch` the browser should automatically reload when it detects a change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I _think_ this is already included in `5.3`, right? Don't believe it needs to be installed, can just add `browserSync({...})` to the `gulpfile`. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#browser-sync)

Comment: @camelCase No, it doesn't come out-of-the-box. It will, however, give you a little error message and the code you need to install it :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help I tried to implement browserSync but couldn't get it to work is there a problem with my gulpfile (check edit)

Comment: @user3818418 Just to double check, to access the homepage of your app you just call `localhost`? Also, unless you already have a process running on port 3000 I would just leave it as the default.

Comment: Ah yes sorry dumb mistake on my behalf took that line away. I'm running on port 8000 so I'll leave the port line there.